# Include jquery-ui-browserify in client

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I', using browserify to transform node modules to browser ones for my express app.

This is the command to browserify

```
browserify -r jquery > ./public/js_app/jquery.js
browserify -r jquery-ui-browserify > ./public/js_app/jquery-ui.js
```

And this is to require jquery

```
var jQuery = require('jquery');
```

this code works fine

```
jQuery("#info-dialog");
```

but I don't know how to include jquery-ui-browserify. I have tried this but not works

```
var jQuery = require('jquery');
require('jquery-ui-browserify');
jQuery("#info-dialog").dialog({
  resizable: false,
  height: 100,
  modal: true
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just `require` jQuery and jQuery UI in one file and then bundle that up? Also, you should assign some variable to `require('jquery-ui-browserify')`. For example: `var jQueryUI = require('jquery-ui-browserify');`

Answer (score 7):

Here's how i'd set this up

### **So, from the top:**

1. create project dir:

   - `mkdir myProject && cd ./myProject` to create directory
   - `npm init` will interactively create your `package.json`
2. install dependencies

   - `sudo npm install jquery jquery-ui-browserify --save`

     - this installs both and `--save` adds them to your package.json
3. Create app structure

   - `mkdir app` will create your main folder
   - `cd app && touch index.html app.js`
4. Write your script in **`app.js`**, requiring and using all you wish:

   - first `var $ = require('jquery'); require('jquery-ui-browserify');`
   - below that, write script as normal
5. Browserify that jank!

   - open terminal, if not still in `/myProject/app/`, cd into it
   - run `browserify ./app.js > ./bundle.js`
6. in index.html, include `<script src='bundle.js'></script>` just before closing body tag and you're ready to rock.

### Example code

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Project</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My Project</h1>
    <input type="text">
    <script src='bundle.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here, just marked up a basic html5 page, included the `bundle.js` file generated by browserify. Now we can use this bundle.

```
// app.js
// NOTE: remember, you code this before running `browserify ./app.js > ./bundle.js`
var $ = require("jquery");
require("jquery-ui-browserify");

$(function() {
  $('input').autocomplete({ source: ['jquery', 'mootools', 'underscore']} );
});
```

Hope this helps! It worked perfectly for me.